# How to log results from a single cell as I recalculate (F9/simulation) in a Excel worksheet over many trials

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a financial simulation. The simulation produces 8 results per run (F9/refresh). I would like to run the simulation which produces results on refresh (F9) and log the 8 values in a table.

I found a macro

```
Sub Macro1()

For i = 1 To 12

Calculate ' code equivalent of hitting F9

Range("d" & i).Value = Range("a1").Value

Next i

End Sub
```

that does this for a single cell;

[image: current simulation results in Excel]

What is need is this;

[image: current simulation results in Excel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines should work:

```
Range("d" & i).Resize(1, 8).Value = Application.Transpose(Range("a1").Resize(8, 1).Value)
```